# How to create MediaIoBaseUpload from webapp2 request corresponding to a HTML form submission

Tags: google-app-engine

I have following HTML form that uploads a file to the server

HTML:

```
<form id="form1" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="submit">
<input type="file" name="file" accept="text/plain,text/html,application/msword,application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document"/>
<div><input id="submit_button" type="submit" value="Upload"/></div>
</form>
```

What is the best way to create a `MediaIoBaseUpload` object on the server corresponding to the file?

Python:

```
def post(self):
        file = self.request.POST['file']                
        # How to create a MediaIoBaseUpload object from file?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this seems to work:

```
media = MediaIoBaseUpload(file.file, mimetype=file.type, resumable=False)
```

Comment: I also found it helps to turn the data string into a stream for the file parameter for MediaIoBaseUpload().
        file = io.BytesIO(data)